# How To Move Layout Items After SDK Update?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just updated my Android SDK/etc (Eclipse IDE) and, while there seems to be some nice, new aspects/features of the Graphical Layout part for xml's, the previous ability of moving items using the Red Arrows up/down is missing and I'm not able to move items around (in or out of layouts).

Yes, I know I can (and guess I'll have to) move the actual xml code around but, I really like the ability to move items graphically.

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ***you*** are missing anything. Whoever wrote the new plugin is though, see:

[Layout Outline in Eclipse lacks Up/Down Plus/Minus buttons](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13042)

Comment: humm... me thinks you're correct.  What a real pain - almost as bad as working with Cocoa/Interface Builder (yuk!)